# Chrome on Android not recognizing Javascript string

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome

The following will display the alert on my computer and on my Android using Firefox, but not on my Android using Chrome.  I'm aware of some of the problems with Chrome when used on an Android, but this one had me up all night trying everything I can think of to get the alert to pop up when using Chrome on an Android.  It's the only hangup in the program I wrote.  What am I missing here?

```
var i = 0;
var test = "456";
var line = "";

for(i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
    line += i;
}
line = line.toString();
if(line.contains(test)) {
    alert(line);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because [String.prototype.contains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/contains) is experimental and part of EcmaScript 6 proposal.

Also checkout the [Browser compatibility section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/contains#Browser_compatibility) on that same page.

Comment: I'll use . . .if (line.indexOf("test") !=-1) {

Comment: I think it should be `test` not `"test"`.